# How can I align the options in lightning:radioGroup horizontally or is there a way to use ui:inputRadio to align the options horizontally?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have two options for the user to choose from within the radio options in lightning. How can they be aligned horizontally?

Comment: Please share your code so far and a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

There is no "horizontal radio group" in Lightning, hence there is no out-of-the-box way to get a horizontal radio group in Lightning. If you want one, you're going to have to build your own component. Any recommendation that we give you (e.g. custom CSS) may break in a future release, so we can't rightly give you a CSS-based solution. Off of the top of my head, you're going to need some lightning:layout, lightning:layoutItem, lightning:input, and aura:iteration, and possibly a smidgen of CSS.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox! However, I used the [radio-button-group](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/radio-button-group/) component  which has better aesthetics than the radio button alone.

Comment: @AdityaSagam I agree, that's what it's meant to be used for.